# How can I pass redirection from and Iframe to Parent page? [Breaking out from an iFrame]

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect, iframe

Please I am tryin to pass redirection or navigate from and iFrame Page to Parent Page. How can I possibly archive this?

Below is my redirection code in the iframe page:

```
<div class="content__wrapper" style="text-align: center"> <button id="#"> <a href="../sign_up"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Start"> </button> </a> </div>
```

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the scope on the main window run:

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => { console.log(event.data) /* your link will be here */ })
```

and in iframe run:

```
window.top.postMessage(redirect_link, '*') // link you want to redirect to
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML that you provided is totally wrong, Why do you have an A tag and an input[type=submit] inside a button and why the A tag starts inside the button tag and ends after the button closing tag.

Anyway, to do what you are looking for you need to use this code:

```
<button onclick='window.top.location="../sign_up"'>Start</button>
```